# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\log(e^{n}+e^{-n})}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How would I show that the following series converges or diverges?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{\log(e^{n}+e^{-n})}$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried doing the integral test? That is what you usually do if you have a logarithm.

Comment: The intuition is that for large $n$, that $e^{-n}$ doesn't really matter - the expression $e^n + e^{-n}$ is like saying "seventy five quadrillion dollars and two cents". So that denominator is basically $\log(e^n)=n$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is completely trivial. $\frac{1}{\log(e^n+e^{-n})}$ is extremely close to $\frac{1}{n}$ for large $n$s and the harmonic series is divergent.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Seeing that it's divergent and proving it are different things...

Comment: @Mehrdad: not so different, at least for this kind of questions.

Comment: I'm saying even if seeing it might be trivial, proving it is not (for a student who's just learning about it). To prove it you have to "know" what inequalities to use to show the bound. That's nowhere nearly as obvious as the fact that the decay rate is too low for it to converge. (The original problem basically screams "this term can be ignored" but it doesn't also tell you how to bound it.)

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't know about series so I won't comment about its triviality but I think this question should be closed as plain homework question.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I don't think that many US Calc II students would find this to be trivial while first learning about it.

Comment: Trivial or not, the OP simply posted their homework on the site, with no personal input whatsoever... or did I miss something?

Comment: @Did, sure, close it because the OP did not bother to provide context, but not because the thing's "trivial" (whatever the hell that means here).

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: You may notice that the question already [went through reopen review once](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/800417). (The link I provided can be found from the [timeline of your post](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2241955/timeline).) It was very likely due to a reopen vote. If I remember the rules correctly, it can still can into the reopen review queue through editing. (However, a question will only be enqueued once per closure via editing.)

Comment: If you are not sure what to add as a context, here are some suggestions: You can mention source of the problem. You could mention whether you would be able to deal with a simpler but somewhat similar problem: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{\log(e^{n})}$. You could mention whether there is some inequality between your series and the well-known harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$. (And whether this inequality is in the right direction to use comparison of the two series.) Perhaps other users will have more suggestions.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician My point is that the whole discussion about whether this question is mathematically trivial or not is a diversion if one is interested in deciding whether the post should be closed or not (and yes, the notion itself of being trivial is ill-founded hence its invocation in a comment above only muddies the water).

Comment: @Did I just wanted to mention that there was [this recent discussion on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26227/should-close-votes-be-used-to-answer-questions). Since this question was linked there, it might be a reason for increased attention to this question and also for some of the above comments. (Perhaps you were already aware of the post on meta. Even if that's the case, this comment might be useful for other users who stumble upon this discussion.)

Comment: @Did Martin is correct, my comment is a direct result of that meta thread. I have no problem with the question being closed due to lack of context because it is a clear HW problem. But I don't think it's reasonable to close this as "trivial", even if it's immediately clear to those with a bit of experience.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Which is my point (ter).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\log(e^n+e^{-n})=n+\log(1+e^{-2n})\le n+e^{-2n}\le 2n$$

Answer (score 14):

How about $$\log(e^n + e^{-n}) \le \log(2 e^n) = \log 2 + n \le 1 + n$$